# which technology to choose to create a web chat client?

Tags: java, rmi

I want to make a chat application which will have a desktop client for it. Also, I want that there should be some kind of software on my server which will be responsible for carrying out all the communication part between different users(who are connected throught the desktop client.). I am well versed with the Java programming language but I am not able to sort which technology(like RMI, servlet, webstart,etc.) will be more suited to this project. Please help me out.

Comment: somebody from my peer group recommended me to do it through java rmi. Will it be good to do the project through java rmi?

Comment: And if your friends told you to jump off of a cliff, would you do that, too?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into the Jabber protocol (XMPP).

Here's an article titled "Building an Instant Messaging Application Using Jabber/XMPP" http://java.sys-con.com/node/232087

Answer (score 1):

The Jetty web container has a chatserver as a sample application.  You may find it easy to adapt to what you need, and then write a desktop client talking http with the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) and a Java backend. The web frontend should be standard compliant, so I would choose JavaScript.

Comment: but the thing is that I want to make a desktop client and also I am not well versed with JavaScripts.

Comment: It all depends on your target users. Are they willing to have Java installed on their clients? Then [JWS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html) would be fine.